# Unable to phrase Keras prediction output

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to create an image classification project using keras. But I am stuck at understanding the output from the trained model. I am having 3 classes and I want to find the most probable class.

Here's the train code:

```
# Importing all necessary libraries
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
 
img_width, img_height = 250, 250

train_data_dir = 'Data/Wheat/Train'
validation_data_dir = 'Data/Wheat/Test'
nb_train_samples =2545
nb_validation_samples = 737
epochs = 10
batch_size = 16

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer='rmsprop',
            metrics=['accuracy'])

from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
model.save('Data/Wheat_model.h5')
```

And my prediction code is :

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.applications.vgg16 import decode_predictions
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
import numpy as np

from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('/content/Data/Wheat_model.h5')

image = load_img('/content/Data/Wheat/1/001.jpg', target_size=(250, 250))
img = np.array(image)
img = img / 255.0
img = img.reshape(1,250,250,3)
label = model.predict(img)
print("Predicted Class: ", label)
```

I am getting the below output with all the images I am trying to predict.

```
Predicted Class:  [[1.]]
```

What does this 1 mean?? I just want the predicted class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code. You say you have 3 classes, therefore your model's top layers should be

```
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

In your generators change the class_mode to

```
class_mode='categorical'
```

change your model compile code to

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
model.compile(Adam(learning_rate=.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now when you do model,predict on a single image the prediction will produce 3 probability outs, one for each class. You need to find the one that has the highest probability as follows

```
# classes is a list of the 3 classes
classes=list(train_generator.class_indices.keys())
pred=model.predict(img)
print ('the shape of prediction is ', pred.shape)
# this dataset has 3 classes so model.predict will return a list of 3 probability values
# we want to find the index of the column that has the highest probability
index=np.argmax(pred[0])
# to get the actual Name of the class use 
klass=classes[index]
# lets get the value of the highest probability
probability=pred[0][index]*100
# print out the class, and the probability 
print(f'the image is predicted as being {klass} with a probability of {probability:6.2f} %')
```

That should do it.